How does Java update variable value?
So, the output of this function is 0.
It is only possible if java updates the values once the entire statement precending ';' has completed. If that is the case, then what's the point of having an equal to operation?
Shouldn't it correspond to, z =x +y-(x+y);
class HelloWorld {
  
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int x = 10;
    int y = 20;
    int z = x += y -= x += y;
    System.out.println(z);
  }
}

I ran the code, and this is what I could infere. I did try searching if my inference is correct, however I didn't find anything on this?
EDIT: My question is - why are we using the value of x = 10, in all the next expressions when x+=y will eventually update the value of x to 30?

Fix your indenting.

z = 10 + (20 - (10 + 20) => z = 10 + (20 - 30) => z = 10 + (-10) => z = 10 - 10 => z = 0. I see no problem here. Read more about operator associativity in Java here: https://www.javatpoint.com/associativity-of-operators-in-java

most important point: do not write code like that; second: check Java Language Specification 15.7. Evaluation Order and 15.26.2. Compound Assignment Operators ||| that expression could be written as int z = (x += (y -= (x += y)));

@user85421 Unfortunately I can only upvote your  comment once.

I don't completely understand what the point of this question is.

@EJoshuaS-StandwithUkraine What's the point of the equality sign if the value is only going to be updated after the entire expression has been finished updating?

Very few if any uses those operators in the middle of an expression. It makes it hard to read and understand expressions. Usually it is used for single statements like x +=y; instead of x= x+y;. It is a leftover from C.

"why are we using the value of x = 10" : the answer is given in the first link I posted before: "If the operator is a compound-assignment operator (§15.26.2), then evaluation of the left-hand operand includes both remembering the variable that the left-hand operand denotes and fetching and saving that variable's value for use in the implied binary operation." and, for example, in a += b -= c (or a += (b -= c)) the result is the result of the  +=, so Java remembers the value of a and then evaluates b -= c

In Java, "Left-Hand Operand Is Evaluated First".
This means that the above expression will be solved like this:
int z = (x = x + (y = y - (x = x + y)));
int z = (x = 10 + (y = y - (x = x + y)));
int z = (x = 10 + (y = 20 - (x = x + y)));
int z = (x = 10 + (y = 20 - (x = 10 + 20)));
int z = (x = 10 + (y = 20 - (30)));
x wil become 30.
int z = (x = 10 + (-10));
x wil become 30.
y will become -10.
int z = (x = 0);
x wil become 0.
y will become -10.
int z = 0;
z will become 0;
